# 'redirect_uri' is invalid for Microsoft login MSAL authentication Azure

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Using login with Microsoft on Azure AD B2C I get the following error:

> invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

I can reach other providers and login with email just not Microsoft.. lol.

I have searched for hours and tried everything I can think of, hopefully someone else can help identify the issue. Initially I was only able to get Microsoft login to work using https://login.microsoft.com/common or something similar but that did not use my userflow/ allow other providers. Now that I have the userflow working from my application I cannot login with Microsoft. Below is my config and code.

I initially followed the Microsoft tutorial here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/single-page-application-azure-login-button-sdk-msal

then pieced others together to get it to use my userflow to execute and it works other than login with Microsoft.

**Registered Application Manifest on Azure:**

```
{
"id": "<ID>",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": true,
"appId": "<app id>",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-06-09T22:15:39Z",
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "Management",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "https://jwt.ms/",
        "type": "Spa"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://jwt.ms",
        "type": "Spa"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "type": "Spa"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "type": "Spa"
    }
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": "http://localhost:3000/",
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
"tags": [
    "notApiConsumer",
    "singlePageApp"
],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
```

}

**azure-authentication-config.tsx**

```
import { Configuration, LogLevel } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const AzureActiveDirectoryAppClientId: any =
  process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_APP_CLIENT_ID;

export const b2cPolicies = {
  names: {
    signUpSignIn: 'B2C_1_dwsdevuserflow01',
    forgotPassword: 'B2C_1_dwsdevuserflow01',
    editProfile: 'B2C_1_dwsdevprofileflow01',
  },
  authorities: {
    signUpSignIn: {
      authority:
        'https://dwsdevb2c.b2clogin.com/dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_dwsdevuserflow01',
    },
    forgotPassword: {
      authority:
        'https://dwsdevb2c.b2clogin.com/dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_dwsdevuserflow01',
    },
    editProfile: {
      authority:
        'https://dwsdevb2c.b2clogin.com/dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_dwsdevprofileflow01',
    },
  },
  authorityDomain: 'https://dwsdevb2c.b2clogin.com',
  // authorityDomain: 'https://login.microsoft.com/common',
 };

export const MSAL_CONFIG: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: AzureActiveDirectoryAppClientId,
    authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
    knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin, // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**azure-authentication-context.tsx**

```
import {
  PublicClientApplication,
  AuthenticationResult,
  AccountInfo,
  EndSessionRequest,
  RedirectRequest,
  PopupRequest,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';

import { MSAL_CONFIG } from './azure-authentication-config';

export class AzureAuthenticationContext {
  private myMSALObj: PublicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(
     MSAL_CONFIG,
  );
  private account?: AccountInfo;
  private loginRedirectRequest?: RedirectRequest;
  private loginRequest?: PopupRequest;

  public isAuthenticationConfigured = false;

  constructor() {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.account = null;
    this.setRequestObjects();
    if (MSAL_CONFIG?.auth?.clientId) {
      this.isAuthenticationConfigured = true;
    }
  }

  private setRequestObjects(): void {
    this.loginRequest = {
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile'],
      prompt: 'select_account',
    };

    this.loginRedirectRequest = {
      ...this.loginRequest,
      redirectStartPage: MSAL_CONFIG.auth.redirectUri, //window.location.href,
    };
  }

  login(signInType: string, setUser: any): void {
    if (signInType === 'loginPopup') {
      this.myMSALObj
        .loginPopup(this.loginRequest)
        .then((resp: AuthenticationResult) => {
          this.handleResponse(resp, setUser);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    } else if (signInType === 'loginRedirect') {
      this.myMSALObj.loginRedirect(this.loginRedirectRequest);
    }
  }

  logout(account: AccountInfo): void {
    const logOutRequest: EndSessionRequest = {
      account,
    };
    this.myMSALObj.logout(logOutRequest);
  }

  handleResponse(response: AuthenticationResult, incomingFunction: any) {
    if (response !== null && response.account !== null) {
      this.account = response.account;
    } else {
      this.account = this.getAccount();
    }

    if (this.account) {
      incomingFunction(this.account);
    }
  }
  private getAccount(): AccountInfo | undefined {
    console.log(`loadAuthModule`);
    const currentAccounts = this.myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();
    if (currentAccounts === null) {
      // @ts-ignore
      console.log('No accounts detected');
      return undefined;
    }

    if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
      // @ts-ignore
      console.log(
        'Multiple accounts detected, need to add choose account code.',
      );
      return currentAccounts[0];
    } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
      return currentAccounts[0];
    }
  }
}
export default AzureAuthenticationContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

In AzureAD navigate to Home => App Registrations > YOUR_APP

Under “Single-page application” you should see the Redirect URIs listed.  It is my understanding that the redirectUri value under Auth in your MSAL_CONFIG file needs to match on of the URI’s listed there.  Have you confirmed that is the case?  I am unable to tell what ‘window.location.origin’ is producing based on your config.

Comment: Hello thank you for responding. I confirmed that http://localhost:3000 is in the redirect uri's. When using the browser console, window.location.origin returns http://localhost:3000. When stepping through with Burp Suite I noticed the redirect uri stays the same until login with MS is selected then it changes to `https://dwsdevb2c.b2clogin.com/dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` the request prior is `GET /dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_dwsdevuserflow01/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?` Do I need to expose an API endpoint for live.com?

Comment: Alright I figured it out lol. In short, you need to add a web redirect uri in my case `https://dwsdevb2c.b2clogin.com/dwsdevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` and create keys. The instructions I had been following only seemed to talk about SPA redirects or I just missed it idk. Either way, It's working and ill post a more descriptive answer for anyone else that comes across this in the future.

Comment: Nice!  I was out of ideas 

Comment: Glad to help :)